# How does the browser render pseudo element selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-content

What I'm particularly wondering is how expensive `*:after` would be, resource-wise.
Would the pseudo element become the key selector in this case? Or would the client grab all the elements anyway?

In other words, what's the difference between the `*:after` and `*` performance-wise?

---

[edited. stupid example. my bad.]

For clarification, I'm trying my hand at drawing sth using only css and found myself using a lot of pseudo elements. Just wandering if I can save myself some time by writing

```css
*:after, 
*:before {
   content:'';
}
```

and its resource cost.

Thanks.

Comment: Even after you edited, am still not getting what you are trying to do with `*:after`

Comment: @Mr. Alien: I think he's asking about comparing the effects of styling an actual element vs styling a pseudo-element, in which case the selector subject isn't too relevant.

Comment: @BoltClock got a clear scenario now, just editing my answer

Comment: @BoltClock and I realized that I gave him same advice :p of using `.container *`

Answer (score 4):

> Would the pseudo element become the key selector in this case?

Technically, the *subject* of the selector is `*`, meaning whichever element is matched by `*` will be the one generating the pseudo-element.

The term "key selector" isn't well-defined when it comes to pseudo-elements, plus unlike the concept of subject selectors it's actually an implementation detail. If "key selector" means "selector representing the box that is rendered", then I suppose you *could* say that the pseudo-element is the key selector. I'm not familiar with implementation details, though, since I'm not an implementer.

Either way, it's safe to assume that the client walks through the DOM and, for every element that it picks out:

1. Attempt to match the element against the selector, ignoring the pseudo-element for now (in this case, `*`).
2. If the element matches the selector, attempt to create a pseudo-element box as a child of this element's box (in the case of generated pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after`) if it is applicable (some elements cannot generate pseudo-elements).
3. Apply styles to the pseudo-element box and render it as with any other box.

The difference between your two selectors is that the former contains a pseudo-element while the latter does not. Since they do fundamentally different things, it's not fair to compare them by performance. However, they both *do* attempt to match any element in the DOM as they both use the same catch-all selector `*`, so barring any special optimizations, it's safe to assume that the only overhead that comes with `*:after` lies with actually generating and rendering the pseudo-element.

Since we're on the topic of performance, remember that matching an element to `*` is almost instantaneous as it's basically a guaranteed match; it's only when you combine it with more complex selectors that it gets more expensive on a selector level, and while ultimately its performance scales the greatest with the number of elements you have in the DOM, it's still not nearly as expensive as actually rendering the styles unless you have elements in the thousands.

---

As for your use case, my opinion is that you generally do not need to create pseudo-elements for every element. If you're drawing something with CSS, see if you can limit your selector by context so you avoid rendering unnecessary boxes across the entire DOM, e.g. if you're only drawing within an element with a certain ID:

```
#mycanvas *:after, 
#mycanvas *:before {
   content:'';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**After Question Edited**

Just got a clear picture of what you are trying to ask here, so when you use `*`, it is going to select the elements anyways but that won't be precise as it selects all elements.. If you want, you can use something like

```
.container *:not(span) {
   color: red;
}
```

Or (But the below one will select all elements nested inside `.container`)

```
.container * {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2D75/)

---

**Before Question Edited**

I am not able to understand what are you asking here, but both selectors are *COMPLETELY DIFFERENT*.. they are used for different purposes, I don't know whether it's a typo in your question, but using `*:after` is often used with `content` which has to be embedded `:before` or `:after`.

So, for example

```
*:after {
    content: " <";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qBYgN/)

And when you use this, `* .after`, will select elements having class `.after`

```
* .after {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/qBYgN/1/)

---

As far as the optimization goes, I don't think using `*` in general websites is a huge performance issue, I often use the selector below holding properties like

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

Also, last but not the least, I don't find any reason to use `*:after` as you won't be embedding some content using `:after` for each element.